# What can be used to replace the if statement in this bit of code written in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, file-io

The following is my attempt to scan a file to search and see if an entered username is taken already. The code doesn't work because of the if statement.

```
for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    /* for loop allows the user to keep entering usernames until they come up with an unused username. */
    FILE *userlist; /*The userlist file holds all the taken usernames */

    userlist = fopen("userlist.txt", "r");
    fseek(userlist, x, SEEK_SET); /* This starts the search at the place x, which is incremented each time. */
    fscanf(userlist, " %s", &username_ext); /* This scans the file contents after x and stores it in the username_ext variable */

    if (strcmp(username, username_ext) == 0) { /* If the username entered and the strings after the x are the same, the loop terminates. */
        printf("\nThe username is already taken.");
        break;
    }
    fclose(userlist);
}
```

Comment: When I comment out the if statement the file is created. Otherwise, the program just terminates due to error.

Sorry, that's wrong. The file isn't created whether or not I comment out the if statement. All that happens is that the program doesn't terminate due to error.

Comment: what does that break statement do?

Comment: Can you come up with full code? @APMullings

Comment: I don't think `fseek()` works like you expect. It doesn't move between the user names you put in the file. It's moving explicitly to the byte offsets 0, 1, 2, etc... up to 99.

Comment: @APMullings Can you add the variables declarations?

Comment: Could you  try `fscanf(userlist," %s", username_ext);` ? See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ : there is a sample code showing how to read  string.

Comment: Way too many comments.  Do not comment the obvious.

Comment: Trying to mix text with binary reading. Open the file once. Read through using `fgets` (removing any trailing `newline`), comparing each line with your name. Remember, `fscanf` will not work if a name contains spaces, such as "Robert De Niro".

Comment: Yeah, the code was terminating because I declared username_ext as a character and not a string. Now it doesn't terminate due to error, but the file is still not created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will never work, especially if each entry in the file is of variable length.

Instead you should open the file *before* the loop, skip the seeking (which will almost never work in a text file, and especially not the way you show it being used). Then you can read a string (using either `fgets` or `fscanf`) and compare to the username given.

Something like the following pseudo-ish code:

```
file = open_file()
while (fscanf("%s", username_ext) == 1)
{
    if (strcmp(username, username_ext) == 0)
    {
        // Username found
    }
}
```

---

To explain why the code, as shown in the question, will never work, the `fseek` call will set the position to the offset `x` in the file from the start. And that offset is in *bytes*, not in "records" or "elements".

And if the input file is a text file where each record is of different length, there is simply no way of seeking to a specific record without knowing its position beforehand.